# php curl - follow relative paths

Tags: php, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use curl with relative path in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615971/is-it-possible-to-use-curl-with-relative-path-in-php)

I have been trying for hours to get a script to work that will follow relative urls.

A quick summary of the problem.

I'm using the `FOLLOWLOCATION` option to follow URLs, but when the url is:

```
/redirectPage.html
```

curl follows it like this:

```
localhost/redirectPage.html
```

Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);


$content = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

The few "solutions" I've found involve parsing the DOM Document and replacing the href attributes with the absolute URL, but I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to still use `FOLLOWLOCATION`. Is there a way to set a base URL in curl, or capture the redirected url that is followed in the `FOLLOWLOCATION` option and append a string to it?

Please help.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6615971/161052

Comment: I saw this but the solution didn't work for me. Resetting the server variables still led to curl following relative paths

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` refers to following redirects received from the webserver, it has nothing to do with interpretation of the original URL. Relative URLs are only meaningful if they're on a web page, they're relative to the URL uses to get to that page. What do you expect your relative URL to be relative to?

Answer (score 0):

`FOLLOWLOCATION` allows `cURL` to follow `Location: /redirects` in the **response headers**. But does not allow you to download relative URLs.

You need to resolve the URL yourself. To resolve a relative URL, you need an absolute one to use as reference. But where do you provide it to cURL? You don't, you can't, you shouldn't.

It's you job to sanitize and resolve URLs. Not the HTTP Client's. cURL resolves relative `Location: headers`. But not relative URL requests based on some previous memory of a page that might have never existed.