# cURL get page content like iframe

Tags: php, curl, iframe, file-get-contents

I want to get page content using cURL but when I get it page css style is not load propertly and I don't know why.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://some-page.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Second thing is that, did I can get using cURL full working page like it is geting page by iframe? For now all links are rewrite so when I want go to subpage it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS (and probably some Javascript as well) don't load because they're using absolute or relative paths that have no meaning on your domain.

You're going to either need to find all these links in the cURL response and replace them with valid URLs on the domain (and probably rewrite regular HTML links and other assets).

Your best bet is probably to configure Apache to act as a reverse proxy so it'll do all this for you.  See [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Comment: I didn't have access to Apache because it is on shared hosting, can you give me some tips how I can do this in other way?

Comment: I was find answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615971/is-it-possible-to-use-curl-with-relative-path-in-php Solved :)