# php + identitiy server, check_session

Tags: php, identityserver4, openid-connect

Users can log in my site via identity server which provides "check_session_iframe". I want to check if users log out of identity server so I can log them out, kill their sessions and force them log in again.I am trying solve this problem this way but I got nothing as a result.

```
  $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "connect/checksession",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0",
    "client_id": "clientid"
  ),
    ]);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($resp);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use curl with relative path in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615971/is-it-possible-to-use-curl-with-relative-path-in-php) (Spoiler: Curl needs an absolute path)

Comment: If ^that doesn't help, you need to give us more info. What does the code in `checksession` look like? As far as we know, that code might be broken so it's hard to debug without it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for answer. the url from outside of my domain. Identity server from another domain.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the URL needs to be absolute. How would cURL know what domain/host it should request if you don't tell it?

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/checksession.html checksession looks like this.

Comment: Since it turns out that it's not your code/server, we don't really need to check that code. Just pass the correct URL (the complete URL) to cURL and test again. You should also add some [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to get some insight into any request issues.